# How can I randomize primary key values?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, primary-key

I need to avoid having my primary keys sequential. Basically looking for this in MySQL: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt

Comment: So you got the code already but are just too lazy to look up the equivalent syntax for MySQL? And you suppose we're going to do the work for you because we have nothing better to do?

Comment: @tombom that's not the case. I have no idea how to translate this to MySQL or if it's actually translatable.

Comment: Well, still you didn't even have a try it seems. You could start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html There are plenty of examples.

Comment: Are you thinking about [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), may be?

Comment: I am curious about the reason you want to do that. If you can share, what is your use case?

Comment: This may do what you need https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/uuid/ but I have no experience with mariadb to be sure if you could use it as PK to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: Does it need to be a "self-inverse"?

Comment: @mustaccio: it's too long

Comment: @Giovanni I don't want the project to look new.

Comment: @RickJames that might be preferable but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE id = 43 * id + floor(43*RAND())
    ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Not totally obfuscated, but might suffice.  And it might be efficient enough -- Note that I am not rearranging the values, and that I am starting at the end in order to avoid duplicate key during the process.  The 43 was picked arbitrarily; something like 10 or 100 would be pretty obvious.